# Multiple conditions in the Choiceset

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to check multiple fields on the Choiceset using the Logical AND OR but it is throwing error.Below is the expression I tried

```
not isEmpty(vars.quoteLineItemId) AND (not isEmpty(payload.PhaseLevelItemNumber) OR not isEmpty(payload.PhaseLevelItemName)
```

And the error is like `Unexpected end of input, expected ')' for the enclosed expression. (line 1, column 124):`

I even tried below expression but no luck

```
 vars.quoteLineItemId!=empty AND (payload.PhaseLevelItemNumber!=empty OR payload.PhaseLevelItemName!=empty)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I suggest to change the *not* with ! as the presedence of ! is clear an the expected one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure to provide sample input and expected output when you ask a question.

**Payload**

```
{
    "PhaseLevelItemNumber": "Hello world!",
    "PhaseLevelItemName": " Hello Mars"
}
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var quoteLineItemId = "asdasdad"
---
not (isEmpty(quoteLineItemId) and ((not isEmpty(payload.PhaseLevelItemNumber) or not isEmpty(payload.PhaseLevelItemName))))
```